# How to create a new user without his own FS but with access to write to only one folder of user that creates him?

Tags: security, users

What are the command(s) to create a new user (not from `su`), give him the ability to write to only one folder which is some directory owned by an already existing user (the one that created him)? Meaning that the folder is already under some existing user's FS. How can I create another user and only let him write to that folder?

I was told [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15078/terminal-command-called-not-from-su-that-would-restrict-process-from-writting-t):

> Use useradd, adduser, or whatever
>   utility your unix variant has to
>   create a user. The easiest way to
>   control access to the directory is to
>   make it and its files (but nothing
>   else) owned by a newly created group,
>   and make the new user a member of that
>   group (and no other group).

but I do not know which commands to use to do such thing. So how to do it?

Comment: These commands are somewhat distribution specific. What is your distribution?

Comment: CentOS and OpenSuse

Comment: It would be helpful to know a little more about your use case. Specifically, do you not want the user to have a home directory, or do you perhaps want him to have a home directory that is owned by someone else? I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: I do not want the user to have a home directory.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to

1. create a group;
2. create a user in that group, without giving that user a home directory to write in;
3. make a certain directory owned by that group and writable by it.

The following commands should do the trick on any Linux distribution.

```
groupadd --system myappgroup
useradd -c 'system user for myapp' -d /none -g myappgroup \
        -M -N -r -s /bin/false myappuser
chgrp myappgroup /path/to/directory
chmod g+rwxs /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can't. The system doesn't know who created a user and by default only root has that privilege. A regular user can not create a user without `su` or `sudo`. At least that's how I understand it.